# Should I be concerned about this poem?

Tags: emotional-well-being

My daughter (11) chose this poem to take to school and present to her class:

> Sometimes when I'm alone I cry because I'm on my own
>   The tears are bitter and warm
>   They flow with life, but take no form, I cry because my heart is torn.
>   I find it difficult to carry on. If I had an ear to confide in, I would cry among my treasured friend
>   But who do you know that stops that long, to help another carry on
>   The world moves fast and it would rather pass by
>   Than to stop and see what makes one cry, so painful and sad
>   And sometimes I cry and no one cares about why.

When her grandparent asked her if she felt like that, she said no, she just liked it. Should I say something to her? If so, what?

Comment: When one of my daughters became interested in sad poems (she loves Rilke), she was a bit older and in the fierce grip of the emotional hazards of the teenage years. I can understand your concern, but given that you write nothing about your daughter except that she's 11 and has grandparents, it's difficult for us to come up with any meaningful advice.

Comment: I doubt liking a morose poem reflects one's own emotions any more than liking Batman reflects one's willingness to abandon social expectations, beat people to bloody meat and destroy other people's property with no known restitution. If she says she just likes it I'd be happy she's taken an interest in something that's not facebook or twitter

Comment: The answer to the question, "What makes you like it?", could be quite useful in determining if she is liking it because of its quality or because of empathizing with its message -- the true question you have, after all.

Answer (score 11):

A person can be moved, or touched by a poem without necessarily sharing the feelings expressed therein.

I don't think you need to be concerned if your daughter is otherwise doing fine.

Your daughter is perhaps just a very thoughtful, empathetic type of person. This is a good thing.

Comment: +1 I actually liked the poem, too - and I never cry from loneliness.